# How do I stop my room's lock from being opened with a coin without unscrewing it?

Tags: locks, security

Occasionally when someone comes over, they will open my door with a dollar coin. This is a pain, and sometimes I am working on something private when they open the door. I would like to be able to make it unopenable with a coin without unscrewing anything. One of my ideas is to wedge something in the lock, but then I might not be able to unlock it.

Comment: you need to provide pictures of the door lock.

Comment: From the description, you are inside the room when they come in? Wedging the door will be easier than wedging the lock.

Comment: Have you tried *asking* them to respect your privacy?

Comment: How many people just happen to have a dollar coin in their pocket? This sounds premeditated.

Comment: It sounds like a privacy lock, little more than a "keep out" sign - but is that true?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica most Canadians and Australians, probably, except for a few who don't carry cash

Comment: So, no offence intended, relatively few ;-) Prolly 80+% Brits, but - and I know that it is usual on this site, but - maybe a location tag? The majority here are prolly murkins, and do not often [encounter dollar coins](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: *I would like to be able to make it unlockable with a coin* - your door is already unlockable with a coin

Comment: Sorry, that was me being confusing. I meant I didn't want it to be openable.

Comment: Google "dinner fork door lock".  Someone should probably write this up as a proper answer, but I haven't time

Answer (score 10):

At its simplest, a door hook on the inside of your door will do the job for about $2. at a hardware store. You twist the hook into one side of the door and the loop on the door frame (or vise-versa). 
 No tools needed.

[image: ![![wire door hook] also [image]

… A simple request on the outside of your door.

Good luck.

Comment: LOL, a two-for-the-price-of-one answer! Have a double upvote!